# Android App do not show on Play Store for LG Leon H345

Tags: android

Android app is not showing when tried to install on LG Leon (H345) phone from T-Mobile using Google Play Store. I have checked version, min app version is  Android 4.4 where as phone is on 5.1.1. Here are permissions in the AndriodManifest file.

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="19"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any require feature tag?

Comment: I can disable some functionlity if autofocus camera is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `autofocus` is [not present on LG LEON H345](http://www.phonemore.com/phone/lg-leon-lte-h345/2204) and you've made it a required field in the manifest here:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true"/>
```

If you change this to below and re-upload, it will show:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

For more, check out the [android:required](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#required) docs:

> When you declare android:required="true" for a feature, you are specifying that the application cannot function, or is not designed to function, when the specified feature is not present on the device

So if you've made a feature mandatory, play store doesn't show the app on devices which don't have that feature.